# task: OpenMP directive name required

Tags: c++, openmp

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <locale>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> pii;
typedef long long ll;

ll fib(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    ll a, b;
#pragma omp task shared(a)
    a = fib(n - 1);
#pragma omp task shared(b)
    b = fib(n - 2);
#pragma omp taskwait
    return a + b;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int n;
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    printf("Result: %lld\n", fib(n));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Visual Studio returns C3001 error **"task: OpenMP directive name required"**.
If I comment all the "pragma" it works fine, so there must be a problem with OpenMP. Some other program with "#pragma omp parallel" works fine, it's just the problem with the "task" directive.
What could be the problem?

Comment: you need to define an environment of parallel tasks e.g. started with "#pragma omp parallel" followed by "#pragma omp single nowait".

Comment: @Bort like this?
#pragma omp parallel {
#pragma omp single 
{
%code%
}
}

Comment: E.g. yes. See your error code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3001). Although, I don't know about supported openmp versions in visual studio. So acraig5075 might be right and it won't work anyways.

Answer (score 6):

Visual C++ [supports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt15eb9t.aspx) the OpenMP 2.0 standard.

OpenMP [introduced](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP3.0-SummarySpec.pdf) tasks with OpenMP 3.0

i.e. It's unsupported.